# Do we need to differentiate between [anxiety], [phobias] and [fears]?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

We currently have 40 questions tagged [anxiety](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anxiety) and it has the following wiki excerpt:

> Coping with anxiety as a parent or non-medical questions on helping a child with their anxiety.

---

3 questions are tagged [phobias](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phobias). No tag wiki excerpt.

---

There are 65 questions tagged [fears](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fears) and this is the tag wiki excerpt:

> Questions regarding analyzing, preventing, or helping a child cope with fearful things in their life.

---

I'm not sure we need all three of them. We may at least get rid of [phobias](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phobias). Interestingly, [one](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/12857/30519) of the three [phobias](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phobias) questions is also tagged [fears](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fears).

Do we need to differentiate between [anxiety](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anxiety) and [fears](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fears)? If so, may the difference between these tags lie in *fearful **things***?

Answer (score 1):

I really feel anxities and fears are different things. Looking at wikipedia's introduction about [anxiety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anxiety), it claims in first paragraph that

> Anxiety is not the same as fear, which is a response to a real or
>   perceived immediate threat, whereas anxiety is the expectation of
>   future threat.

While wikipedia isn't a source in itself, I do agree with the distinction, as I personally often experience anxiety, and not much fear.

Maybe your confusion rather comes from the description of the anxiety tag that needs rework, instead.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to tackle the issue, we need to answer two questions first:

**1) Is there a difference between *fear*, *anxiety* and *phobia*?**

**Fear**

> - It’s a natural response to a threat that can be either perceived or
>     real. (1)
> - Fear is the emotional response to real or perceived imminent threat,
>     [...]. (2, citing DSM-5)

**Anxiety**

> - Anxiety is a word we use for some types of fear that are usually to
>     do with the thought of a threat or something going wrong in the
>     future, rather than right now. (1)
> - [A]nxiety is anticipation of future threat. (2, citing DSM-5)

**Phobia**

> - A phobia is an extreme fear of a particular animal, thing, place or
>     situation. People with phobias have an overwhelming need to avoid any
>     contact with the specific cause of the anxiety or fear. (1)
> - Phobias are anxiety disorders involving fear or anxiety that is
>     excessive or out of proportion to the object or situation. (2)

<sub>Sources:

(1) [How to overcome fear and anxiety](https://www.mentalhealth.org.uk/publications/overcome-fear-anxiety), Mental Health Foundation

(2) [Classifying Anxiety: Understanding the Difference Between Fear and Phobia](https://online.grace.edu/news/human-services/difference-between-fear-and-phobia/), Grace College Online</sub>

So my answer is **yes**.

**2) Is the difference important from a parenting perspective?**

When determining which tags to keep / create, this is also an important question to ask and answer. Imagine questions about a child's spending the whole day on the Internet - it would not make sense to have individual tags for each and every site (the question may even be answerable if we don't distinguish, for example, between forum activity or playing browser games).

Another point to consider is whether the tags are used the way they should. This is usually a minor point as incorrectly tagged questions can be edited. However, it could turn out that one tag is always incorrectly used and that there actually are no questions for this tag.

Also keep in mind that *requests for medical advice* are off topic. For example, we have the tag [injury](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/injury) for parenting questions about injuries - do we need to differentiate further? Not really, as how to treat them is mostly out of our scope. Further explanation can be given in the body of the question instead.

Too many questions are tagged [fears](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fears) and/or [anxiety](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anxiety) to too much into detail. While some questions are mistagged, there are enough questions for both tags to make keeping them sensible.

So my answer is **yes**.

Only 3 questions are tagged [phobias](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phobias):

[What are good approaches to lessen fear of insects in a child?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/12621/30519)

[How to help a child overcome fear of heights](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/12857/30519)

[How to help a child with a long-term weather phobia?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/21162/30519)

They all describe a *phobia*, so the tag seems appropriate. On the other hand, questions 1 and 2 could be tagged [fears](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fears), while question 3 might be [anxiety](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anxiety) instead. I feel that in this case, like in the *injury* example above, we could do without the more specific tag. The body of the question could then be used to specify the problem.

So my answer is rather **no**.

**Conclusion**

I suggest to keep [fears](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fears) and [anxiety](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anxiety). If you find mistagged questions, edit them or suggest an edit. Improve the tag wiki excerpts, especially the [anxiety](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anxiety) one to give a brief description of what anxiety is. Maybe also add a reference to the other tag to guide users when to use which one.

I suggest to [burninate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120642/377968) [phobias](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phobias). Do *not* make it a synonym of either [fears](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fears) or [anxiety](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anxiety), since a phobia can be based on either one. Instead, users should use the appropriate tag [fears](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fears) or [anxiety](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anxiety) and then describe the phobia further in the body of the question. Unless we suddenly get many more *on topic* questions about phobias specifically, we can do without [phobias](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phobias) for the moment. If you have too few questions, the tag becomes less useful for searching.